# Why was this question closed as "too broad"?

Tags: support

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/204021/how-do-i-deal-with-online-trolling-harassment-in-video-games

Comment: While I think this question is too broad, if it's refined a bit you might get a better response on [Community Building SE](http://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/), whose expertise is probably more helpful in this instance.

Answer (score 6):

Originally I was okay with the question, but then I thought about it and do believe it's too broad. Or perhaps "Unclear what you're asking".

Deal with online trolling how, exactly? Are you asking how to physically deal with the trolls, either by preventing them from playing or tracing them to their house and punching them in the face? Or are you asking how to mentally cope with trolling? Or both? If you're asking for every possible solution under the sun, it seems to broad since this can be highly dependent on the game.

This question would probably be better if it was about a particular game or specifically about "How do I mentally deal with this?" (though the latter still isn't a great question (though probably not off-topic), as answers are probably just going to be general fluff like "take a break", "ignore them", or "remember that they're probably either 12 years old, or 40 years old and living in their mom's basement."

Comment: Disclaimer: I voted to reopen it before I thought about it enough, so if it ends up reopened with my name attached, that's why.

Comment: Well, you can't possibly think that the OP of that question is asking about how he can trace someone so he can punch him in the face... the "mentally" is implied. Just not written.

Comment: @Lyrion Given that the question was self-answered, and part of that answer was "Use in-game reporting tools", I don't think you can assume the "mentally" was implied.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning, though, that if the question ends up reopened I certainly don't feel strongly enough about it to cast a close vote.